# Laravel 5.7 and Wordpress 5.1 as Frontend

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

Laravel 5.7 and Wordpress 5.1 as Frontend

I need them on the same domain and WP should be front-end as an easy content update solution. It means that all WP files will be in "public_html" folder and Laravel "public_html/app/". Both will have their MySQL Database done thru cPanel. WP index file will be "public_html/index.php" and Laravel will be "public_html/app/laravelindex.php". Both will use ".htaccess" file in their own folder like WP "public_html/.htaccess" and Laravel "public_html/app/.htaccess".

Can I use WP ".htaccess" file for Laravel too, if yes please copy the whole code.

Or if not then please copy whole code for Laravels ".htaccess" file.

Below is the current "public_html/.htaccess" code for you to modify.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Have you considered a subdomain? It'll make this a lot easier.

Comment: What are you trying to achive by mixing up CMS and Framework ? Either pick one or add subdomain as @ceejayoz said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at a subdomain 100%, I've wasted hours trying to do this.

If you are using Forge, create a subdomain for the app (user.domain.com) and install Wordpress on the (domain.com).

Remember not to use the same database, username and password for both Wordpress & Laravel. This would be unwise due to security.